# Merge statement getting duplicate error on DML

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace table catalog_page(
    cp_catalog_page_sk number,
    cp_catalog_page_id text,
    cp_start_date_sk number,
    cp_end_date_sk number,
    cp_department text,
    cp_catalog_number number,
    cp_catalog_page_number number,
    cp_description text,
    cp_type text);
    
create or replace table dem0_json (
    o_type text,
    cp_catalog_page_sk number,
    cp_catalog_page_id text, 
    cp_start_date_sk number,
    cp_end_date_sk number,
    cp_department text, 
    cp_catalog_number number,
    cp_catalog_page_number number,
    cp_description text,
    cp_type text);
```

```
insert into catalog_page (cp_catalog_page_sk,   cp_catalog_page_id, cp_start_date_sk,   cp_end_date_sk, cp_department,  cp_catalog_number,  cp_catalog_page_number  ,cp_description, cp_type) values
    (1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv', 'bi-annual'),
    (2, 'AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 2, 'English areas will leave prisoners. Too public countries ought to become beneath the years.', 'bi-annual'),
    (3, 'AAAAAAAADAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 3, 'Times could not address disabled Indians. Effectively public ports c' , 'bi-annual'),
    (6, 'AAAAAAAAGAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 6, 'Exciting principles wish greatly only excellent women. Appropriate fortunes shall not', 'bi-annual'),
    (7, 'AAAAAAAAHAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 7, 'National services must not come at least into a girls', 'bi-annual'),
    (8, 'AAAAAAAAIAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 8, 'Areas see early for a pounds. New goods study too serious women. Unwittingly sorry incentives shall', 'bi-annual'),
    (10, 'AAAAAAAAKAAAAAAA',2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 10, 'Careful, intense funds balance perhaps boys. Romantic chips remove legs. Direct birds get ', 'bi-annual'),
    (12, 'AAAAAAAAMAAAAAAA',2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 12, 'Girls indicate so in a countries. Natural, emotional weeks try a', 'bi-annual');
```

source as json data

```
insert into dem0_json (o_type ,CP_CATALOG_PAGE_SK, CP_CATALOG_PAGE_ID, CP_START_DATE_SK, CP_END_DATE_SK, CP_DEPARTMENT, CP_CATALOG_NUMBER, CP_CATALOG_PAGE_NUMBER, CP_DESCRIPTION, CP_TYPE)
    values 
    ('U', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual'),
    ('I', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual'),
    ('D', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual'),
    ('I', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual');
```

```
    
MERGE INTO catalog_page AS t 
    USING dem0_json AS s 
        ON t.dem0_json = t.dem0_json 
WHEN MATCHED AND s.o_type='U' THEN 
    UPDATE 
WHEN MATCHED AND s.o_type='D' THEN 
    DELETE 
WHEN MATCHED AND s.o_type='I' THEN 
    INSERT
```

Comment: MERGE INTO CATALOG_PAGE T USING dem0_json S  ON T.dem0_json=S.dem0_json 
WHEN MATCHED AND o_type='U' THEN UPDATE
WHEN MATCHED AND o_type='D' THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND o_type='I' THEN INSERT

Comment: Please format your code. And avoid screaming in the title.

Comment: There is no dem0_json column in either your source or target table - so your merge statement doesn’t make a lot of sense. Also, as well as formatting your code so it is readable, please put the merge statement in your question rather than distributing the required information across different posts

Comment: @RajkumarD if you want somebody to answer, you will need to clearly formulate your question first.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem is the you are thinking row-by-row, and that is not how Snowflake does a merge, thus the section of doc's talking about [Nondeterministic Results](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#nondeterministic-results-for-update-and-delete)

> When a merge joins a row in the target table against multiple rows in the source, the following join conditions produce nondeterministic results (i.e. the system is unable to determine the source value to use to update or delete the target row):

> In this situation, the outcome of the merge depends on the value specified for the ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE session parameter:
>
> If TRUE (default value), the merge returns an error.
> If FALSE, one row from among the duplicates is selected to perform the update or delete; the row selected is not defined.

That very last bit is the hint, snowflake is doing these operations in "one pass" aka all the deletes, then all the update, then all the inserts. and a row is only in one of those steps.

Your data has 4 operations happening to the same rows. AND worst you have no order of operations keys. And there is no such things as "row order"

What you need is an order as well thus like:

```
insert into dem0_json (o_order, o_type ,CP_CATALOG_PAGE_SK, CP_CATALOG_PAGE_ID, CP_START_DATE_SK, CP_END_DATE_SK, CP_DEPARTMENT, CP_CATALOG_NUMBER, CP_CATALOG_PAGE_NUMBER, CP_DESCRIPTION, CP_TYPE)
    values 
    (1, 'U', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual'),
    (2, 'I', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual'),
    (3, 'D', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual'),
    (4, 'I', 1, 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA', 2450815, 2450996, 'DEPARTMENT', 1, 1, 'In general basic characters welcome. Clearly lively friends conv','bi-annual');
```

and then you need to fold the results down.

if the last op is a delete, it's a delete, and all the prior don't matter.

if chains of updates should stack (if only partial values are transmitted, but it appears to have a "full row")

if the last row is an insert, yet the row existed it should become an update.

the folding process might require using a recursive CTE. But once the data is folded. Then you do a single MERGE with that.

Here is some example folding test data with the folded outcome in comment (assume only valid input ever comes in)

```
with dem0_json(o_order, o_type ,CP_CATALOG_PAGE_SK, value) as (
    SELECT * FROM values 
    (1, 'U', 1, 'A'), -- U
    
    (2, 'I', 2, 'B'), -- I
    
    (3, 'D', 3, 'C'), -- D
    
    (4, 'I', 4, 'D'),   
    (5, 'U', 4, 'A'), -- I 5
   
    (6, 'I', 5, 'D'),   
    (7, 'D', 5, 'A'), -- no op

    (8, 'D', 6, 'D'),   
    (9, 'I', 6, 'A'), -- U 5
   
    (10, 'U', 7, 'D'),   
    (11, 'D', 7, 'A'), -- D

    (12, 'U', 8, 'D'),   
    (13, 'U', 8, 'A'), -- U 13
)
```

Comment: create or replace TABLE TEST (
 ID NUMBER(38,8) NOT NULL,
 ITEM_NUM NUMBER(38,8) NOT NULL,
 SHORT_NAME VARCHAR(60)
 constraint TEST_PK primary key (ID, ITEM_NUM)
);

Comment: in my json data am getting 3 different records

Comment: 1,123,'raj','I', 1/1/2020 15:47:01
1,123,'raj','D', 10/1/2020 18:47:01
1,123,'raj','I', 10/1/2020 01:47:01

Comment: while executing my merge statement an getting duplicating error with dml. If i use qualify row_number() over(partition ID, ITEM_NUM order by last_update desc)=1. only new record getting inserted. as per merge statement it should insert statement then delete and then it should insert

Comment: Please give solution for my issue

Comment: @RajkumarD I understand you would like me to write some folding code for you, BUT its rather completed, very data specific and I cannot be bothered investing the 30+ minutes to do it. I have explained you need to write a folding. If that means nothing to you, then good luck.