# Oracle golden gate Json data

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

while loading json data in snowflake am getting 3 types of record. operation type (u,i,d). Below insert statement are the sample data from source table and it have 3 type of records for same appl_id whereas appl_id  is key column in target column. Am getting duplicate error while loading this data using merge statement .
merge into target tgt using demo_tab src on tgt.appl_id =src.appl_id when matched and op_type='U' then update when matched and op_type='D' then delete when not matched and op_type='I' then insert

note: am getting duplicate error while using statement.
if I use qualify row_number() over (parition by appl_id order by last_update  desc) -- only latest record getting inserted or updated

as per json data first record getting inserted ,then update, then delete and then finally it should get inserted, Please guide me

Comment: create table demo_tab(op_type varchar(2),appl_id number(100),last_update date);
insert into demo_tab('I',111,'2022-01-01');
insert into demo_tab('U',111,'2022-01-02');
insert into demo_tab('D',111,'2022-01-05');
insert into demo_tab('I',111,'2022-01-031');

Comment: Share exact statement you are using and possibly data set too as you get and as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge statement getting duplicate error on DML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561886/merge-statement-getting-duplicate-error-on-dml)

Answer (score 0):

You asked this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561886/merge-statement-getting-duplicate-error-on-dml) (but with more actually useful details on the 21st April)

Back then I told you YOU will need to learn to fold your data into a coherent single event per "id" or what ever token is the primary key of your system, I even gave you data to demonstrate the class of work you need to do.

This is not a trivial 10 minute of SQL and is VERY specific to your data and how you want to handle the folding process.